# jquery statement - issue of selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I do some debugging and I found this statement:

```
$(this)[widget.widgetName](widget.attributes);
```

where widget.widgetName = chart

What is the meaning of this statement in jquery?

In the stack I saw that jquery_ui calls _createwidget of jquery-ui

Why does createwidget get called ?

Regards,
Yossi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)[widget.widgetName]` uses square bracket notation to refer to the property whose value is the value of `widget.widgetName`. For comparisons between square backet and  "dot notation"  see the [MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

As you said `widget.widgetName` is `chart`, it's refering to:

```
$(this).chart
```

and then the `(widget.attributes);` is simply invoking the function and passing `widget.attributes` as the first and only parameter:

```
$(this).chart(widget.attributes);
```

As for "Why does createwidget get called?" The `chart()` function must call it, either implicitly (through another function) or explicitly.

Comment: Does the method create,chart,... are method of jquery ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this)[widget.widgetName]
```

refers to the propert of **$(this)** defined by **widget.widgetName**

in this case it is simply

```
$(this).chart
```

Comment: But there is a continue to this statement $(this)[widget.widgetName](widget.attributes) , what is the meaning of (widget.attributes) in this case ?

Comment: I was about to add to this answer and answer your question but @Matt seems to have gotten there first, and there is no point repeating his answer when I agree with it.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to a jQuery object. In this case, you're inside an event handler, element selector, or some other sort of jQuery context where `$(this)` refers to to the jQuery object in the outside selector.